# ActionController::RoutingError: uninitialized constant Api::V1::ApiController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-routing, rails-api

I have Rails 5 API project for controlling user tasks and I have the following error but not always for the same controller and route.

```
ActionController::RoutingError: uninitialized constant Api::V1::ApiController
```

I describe you a little bit my project to explain in more detail the error.

**App structure**

[image]

**Routes**

```
scope module: 'api' do
  namespace :v1 do

    # => Login routes
    scope module: 'login' do
      match 'login', to: 'sessions#login', as: 'login', via: :post
    end

    # => Team routes
    scope module: 'team' do

      # => no admin routes
      resources :tasks, except: [:index] do
        collection do
          match ':view', to: 'tasks#index', as: 'tasks', via: [:get, :post]
        end
      end
    end

  end
end
```

**API Controller**

```
module Api
  class ApiController < ApplicationController

    def respond_with_errors(object)
      render json: {errors: ErrorSerializer.serialize(object)}, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end

  end
end
```

**Team Controller**

```
module Api::V1
  class Team::TeamController < ApiController
```

**Tasks Controller**

```
module Api::V1
  class Team::TasksController < Team::TeamController
```

**Login Controller**

```
module Api::V1
  class Login::LoginController < ApiController
```

**Sessions Controller**

```
module Api::V1
  class Login::SessionsController < Login::LoginController
```

When I execute login route and after tasks route, I get the error in last route and all the routes in team module. If I change the project and save it (only one blank space) and then I execute tasks route and after login route, I get the error in last route and all the routes in login module.

It doesn't have any sense...

**Rails server in this errors**
[image]
[image]

Comment: show your `app/controllers/api/v1/api_controller.rb` file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be using the right constant while inheriting - `::Api::ApiController`:

```
module Api::V1
  class Team::TeamController < ::Api::ApiController
```

because otherwise it is searching for `Api::V1::ApiController`, but should search for `Api::ApiController`

Comment: My API Controller is outside V1 folder.

Comment: @carro always make sure you use the correct constant :)

Answer (score 3):

Right now you have `Api::ApiController`.
Your `app/controllers/api/v1/api_controller.rb` is missing `V1` in namespace

```
module Api::V1
  class ApiController < ApplicationController
    ..
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**

If your `ApiController` is outside `V1` folder then you should do

```
module Api::V1
  class Team::TeamController < ::Api::ApiController
```

Comment: My API Controller is outside V1 folder.

Comment: camon, this is just stolen from my answer :)

Comment: no, it's your who stole it. I wrote comment to the question initially and was about to answer it.

Comment: it does not matter who wrote the comment, it is the answer that you have edited after I realized I was wrong with my first one. Have guts to admit

Comment: @Andrey Deineko carro has commented my answer too (he even has done it 1 minute earlier than your answer). So I have updated it. Yes, after that I have saw that you have done it too (even in the same way).

Comment: not going to discuss this further. answers' edition time speaks for itself :)

Comment: I just have not saw it at the time. I never stole any answer.