# Adding API endpoint to existing Rails 5 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I  need to add an API endpoint to a Rails (5.0.2) app so I have created a `TransitController` under `app/controllers/api`.

The controller, for now, looks like

```
module Api   
  class TransitController < ActionController::Api
    def create 
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :status => :ok, :nothing => true }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I have updated my `routes` as follows

```
  namespace :api do
    post 'transits', to: 'transits#create'
  end
```

But now, when I try to hit the endpoint via curl I get

> ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant
>   ActionController::Api)

In Rails 5+, shouldn't `ActionController::Api` be available by default?

Am I missing anything here?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActionController::RoutingError: uninitialized constant Api::V1::ApiController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40039279/actioncontrollerroutingerror-uninitialized-constant-apiv1apicontroller)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is available, but you need to use `API` instead of `Api`.

So change this:

```
class TransitController < ActionController::Api
```

to:

```
class TransitController < ActionController::API
```

More information [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/API.html).